# How to remove TFS project only locally?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I accidentally mapped the wrong code to my computer from TFS. I want to remove it from my local system so I don't accidentally change it, but I'm also worried that if I don't properly remove it, I might change something or worse delete the code on the server as well. How do I safely remove the project from my computer only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to Team Explorer, and under Connect, select Configure Team Projects...

A dialog will open that will allow you to select which projects you are connected to. Uncheck the project that you mapped accidentally.

You can then safely delete the code from your local computer in Windows Explorer.

You should note, that even if you don't do the disconnect from the project, deleting the files from your local folder in Windows Explorer will not have any impact on TFS. You would have to delete the files in Visual Studio, which would cause a check out. To complete the deletion you would have to check the files back into TFS.

Also, all changes in TFS are non-destructive. Even if you checked out all the files, deleted them, and checked the changes in, you can rollback that deletion in TFS.

It is a very safe source control system. It is very hard to screw up from a user standpoint.